# Can I call OnCommand programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have in the master page an overridden method for `OnCommand` method.

Can I call it programmatically through any page uses the master page?

I mean something like the following:

```
CallOnCommand("CommandName", "CommandArg");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose OnCommand as a public method in your master page:

```
public void CallOnCommand(string name, string commandArgument) 
{
    OnCommand(new CommandEventArgs(name, commandArgument));
}
```

This can be called from any Page that has a reference to the instance of the Master page.

Comment: This needs casting the MasterPage reference to a certain masterpage clas. I hoped there's a better way!

Comment: If you need to call a new method, you need to know the type. OnCommand is `protected` by design, as it should be, so you cannot call it without defining a new method. If your problem is that you have mutiple `MasterPage`s that need this, I would suggest defining an interface for the needed method(s). Then you can cast any MasterPage to one interface and call the method.

Comment: Thanks very much. I wonder what does the `LinkButton` control do when it's clicked? don't I have the same functionality !!

Comment: The LinkButton raises OnCommand on itself. Not on the page. Therefore LinkButton calls OnCommand internally within the same class, which it can do.